# How to check the login functionality is work or not in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm new in ruby on rails. I create simple login function.

But the login page is didnot go sucess page even the credential is valid.

I didnot know why this is happen. Please any one help what mistake i done.

I enclose my code is below,

**Controller userlists_controller.rb**

```
  def login
  end

  def login_action
      user = Userlist.find_by(email: params[:email])
      if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        session[:user_name] = user.name
        redirect_to user, alert: "User logged in successfully"
      else
        redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
      end
  end
```

**View login.html.erb**

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <p id="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag do %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :email, 'Email' %>
        <%= email_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :password, 'Password' %>
        <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%=submit_tag "Login" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**route routes.rb**

```
  get 'login' => 'userlists#login'
  post 'login' => 'userlists#login_action'
```

Comment: You can debug by inserting `puts 'success'` inside the `if` block and `puts 'failure'` inside the `else` block. Also to redirect you'll need either the prefix with `_url` or `_path`. So `redirect_to user` won't work, try `redirect_to user_path` (if this route exists). Let us know.

Comment: @alexalth Note: `redirect_to user` does work, because `user` is an instance of `User` and as such is the equivalent/shortcut of writing `user_path(user)`. Instead op `puts` I would recommend using `Rails.logger.debug "some message"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in  **login.html.erb**

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <p id="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag '/login', {:method => :post } do  %>
<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email, 'Email' %>
    <%= email_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password, 'Password' %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%=submit_tag "Login" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Try like this in **userlists_controller.rb** for login_action method

```
def login_action
  user = Userlist.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    session[:user_name] = user.name
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "User logged in successfully"
  else
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
  end
end
```

And finally check `user = Userlist.find_by(email: params[:email])` object. You are getting any values or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post the comment here as an answer so people will know it works

> Note: `redirect_to user` does work, because `user` is an instance of
>   `User` and as such is the equivalent/shortcut of writing
>   `user_path(user)`. Instead op `puts` I would recommend using
>   `Rails.logger.debug "some message"`